# What's the best way to wrap Label and Input elements

Tags: html, forms

I'm working on a HTML5 form and I want to float some input elements and their labels. Its this the best way to do it?

```
<form>
    <fieldset class="float_left">
        <label for="login">Login ID #</label>
        <input type="text" name="login" id="login">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="float_right">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </fieldset>
    <span class="forgot_login float_left"><a href="#">Forgot your login information?</a></span>
    <input type="submit" value="LOG IN" class="form_button float_right">
</form>
```

I seen people wrap them in divs, lists, etc. I want to follow the best practice. Should I also wrap every label and input elements with a fieldset even if I don't plan on styling it? Ex:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Full Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="First Name" class="float_left">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Ex: johndoe@gmail.com" class="full_input">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <textarea rows="3" name="message" id="message" placeholder="1000 Character or less" class="full_input"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="SEND" class="form_button float_right">
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use CSS, I can't see it in the example above.

Comment: I just want to focus on the HTML part of the code. Since the css if just a float:left, float:right, and some styling for the button.

Comment: Why are people close-voting? Seems like a valid question to me.

Comment: not I, don't scoff at me :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primary, original purpose of a `fieldset` is to convey a contextual association between multiple input fields to *non-visual* agents. It is expected that a screen reader is going to read the `legend` text, then the first field, then the legend, then the next field... As in: "Address: Street 1... Address: Street 2... Address: City..."

For sighted people, a `fieldset` does visually imply a container-type relationship of the same kind: those fields are related by context, but only when there are multiple fields.

So it never makes semantic sense to have a single label/field (a `label` is not a field, in that it does not accept input) in a `fieldset`. It's just annoying to people using screen readers (because it behaves like a redundant label). To sighted people it destroys the implication of relationship if you use it for single fields *and also* multiple fields, and takes up a lot more space.

In short, use it sparingly, semantically, and correctly - not as a styling device.

For a 'neutral' container, use a `div` or a `span`, because they carry no semantic information. List structures, paragraphs, all other elements have semantics and you need to be careful about how you use them.

People will tell you crazy things about the semantics of HTML elements. Don't take anyone at their word, including me. Go read the [spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/) and know it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Using `fieldset` for a combination of a label and a control is illogical, though formally valid: a `fieldset` is supposed to be a *set* of fields.

Other than that, the question is largely a matter of opinion and debate. HTML5 more or less favors `p` for such a pair, but that causes an empty line by default, so `div` is a more reasonable choice. There are also good reasons to use a `table` element, with one row for each label/control pair.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you plan to use a `fieldset` `legend` then I wouldn't bother using `fieldset`s. Bootstrap forms is a nice way to get started too http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms there is no best way though.

You often see people using a wrapper `div` because it helps with creating a neater row i.e. apply padding to a wrapper instead of to all elements within it or floating all elements within a parent and applying a clear-fix element at the bottom to wrap correctly.. or just float the parent as well.